# Simultaneous data tranfer by ethercat

Tags: ethernet, transfer

is it possible to read and send data to few devices connected in series using EtherCAT ? 
I was searching in documentation but i didn't find it.

Thank much for any help

Comment: I’m an EtherCAT expert. I’ll need more information to fully answer your question. Are you asking about sending non-EtherCAT data over the EtherCAT network? Or just generally how EtherCAT is working? With EtherCAT you would map the objects from each slave that you are interested in updating or reading. Then in every cycle the master would send the new information or read out the new information from all the slaves on the network (like a train going around).

Answer (score 0):

*Not an expert here, but with some insights.*

With ref to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherCAT

If you read the initial paragraphs, and then continue through
1.2 Protocol
1.3 Performance
1.4 Topology
I believe you will have all the answers.

As I understand; EtherCAT uses the standard Ethernet hardware (for availability and price), sends standard TCP/IP frames but doesn't use all the available data in the frames. In the devices, the frame handling appears to be in hardware - again for speed - but as the devices may be e.g. encoders it also is a plus to not need code taking up space in the often small memory layouts.